# How to enable automatic closure of brackets in GNU Octave?

Tags: editor, octave, gnu, octave-gui

I want to enable automatic bracket closure in my GNU Octave editor window. In other words when I type start of bracket `(` , the editor must put a closing bracket `)` automatically and put my cursor between both the brackets

I tried looking for options under `Edit > Preferences` but unfortunately couldn't find that option

Comment: I would use a better editor if I were you... :)

Comment: Sure, please could you help point out suggestions?

Comment: Sure. What's your OS? ---- you can set the default editor using [`EDITOR()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/EDITOR.html).

Comment: OS= Windows. Can I use PyCharm as default editor?

Comment: Yes, you can use PyCharm. There's a plugin for MATLAB syntax that you would want to install. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10941-matlab-support

Comment: @CrisLuengo - any comments about integrated features like inline debugging, profiling, etc., compared to the default editors for octave and/or matlab?

Comment: @NickJ I have no experience with that. I use one of the other JetBrains editors with that plugin, all it does is syntax highlighting. You can do debugging and profiling on the MATLAB or Octave command line, so it is possible that there's some 3rd party editor that can do these things. I haven't run into any of them, but also haven't looked very carefully. MathWorks recently put out a plugin for Visual Studio Code, it doesn't yet do debugging or profiling, but maybe one day they'll add that? https://blogs.mathworks.com/matlab/2023/04/26/do-you-use-visual-studio-code-matlab-is-now-there-too/